# object has no attribute 'encode' python 3 requests with auth

Tags: python, api, python-requests

don't do much hashing or encrypted server connections but trying to make the best of it,

I'm trying to play around with the coinbase API as their documentation is pretty direct https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/?python#signing-a-message

I've reached a point where I'm stuck getting the error 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode' when trying pass my message variable into a new hmac, all my parameters for my key, secretkey, passphrase are all strings, I have tried encoding them as ascii and as base64 and as utf-8 and I get the same error

I'm assuming my encryption ordering is somehow the problem but I haven't been able to find anything useful on other stack overflow that matches my issue so far, hoping someone can at least point out what I'm missing

```py
def get_accounts(self):
        print("getting accounts")
        secret = bytes(self.secret, 'UTF-8')

        #unicode objects must be encoded before hashing?? what is that??
        timestamp = str(time.time())
        message = timestamp + 'GET' + self.baseurl + 'accounts' + ''
        message = bytes(message, 'UTF-8')
      
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(secret)
     
  
        signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256)
        print("signature ",signature)

#getting stuck here
        signature_b64 = signature.digest().encode('base64').rstrip('\n')

        headers = {
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature_b64,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
            'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': self.passphrase,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
       
        r = requests.get(self.baseurl + 'accounts', headers=headers)
        print (r.json())
```

Comment: Try _not_ encoding `message` (note that it isn't encoded in the docs that you linked).

Comment: @snakecharmerb I just gave it a shot unfortunately that didn't make a difference, could it maybe be that ```hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret)``` is being passed a string instead of a base64 encoded value and being asked to decode it?

Comment: Yes, it looks like `hmac_key` and `message` should both be encoded.

Comment: so I found a way to encode them and that does let me calculate a new hmac now, however I'm now stuck on making the signature_64 variable, I have updated my code as well now getting  ```'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'``` at that variable my hmac object is as follows btw signature  <hmac.HMAC object at 0x000002940B1CC270>

Comment: I would do `signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature.digest()).rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: I've tried this and a few other combinations but unfortunately I get the same error, not sure where to go at this point

Comment: I've tried this and a few other combinations but unfortunately I get the same error, not sure where to go at this point, I've found that by using hexdigest() instead of digest() I get an actual string out instead of a byte string, but after that trying the above suggestion with hexdigest() I'm getting ```a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```

Answer (score 0):

okay I got it to produce a normal base64 encoded string, the coinbase api says the signature isn't valid but that's technically a separate issue so I'll leave that alone for now

```
        signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(bytes(signature, 'UTF-8'))
        signature_b64 = signature_b64.decode("utf-8") 
        
        print('final',signature_b64)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue as this one now. We can look at the python cbpro library: https://github.com/danpaquin/coinbasepro-python/blob/5658b2212b0fe39dde18b792f34aeaf81dda6640/cbpro/cbpro_auth.py#L27-L30 but still get the 'invalid signature' error.